# jQuery: How-to toggle display on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have 2 spans.

First one: `<span class="body">`
Second one: `<span class="desc">`

My CSS:

```
.desc {display: none;}
```

What I want to do, is show the second span, when hovering the first. No fancy effects or anything, just show the span.
I know there is a simple jQuery solution out there, but I'm new to jQuery so I'd appreciate some help finding it. ;)

This is what I have so far. Is the syntax correct?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".body").hover(function () {
        $(".desc").toggle();
    })
})
</script>
```

### UPDATE!

As @thenduks pointed out, this results in every `.desc` element to show when a `.body` is hovered. As you can probably imagine, I have several `.body` and `.desc` and I only want the corresponding `.desc` to show on hovering the `.body`.

This is part of my markup: (the whole site is still just local, so I can't give you an url to test - sorry)

```
<ul class="form">
    <li>
      <label class="grid_3 alpha caption" for="from_name">Navn/Firma</label>
      <span class="grid_4 body"><input type="text" id="from_name" name="form[from_name]" size="20" value=""></span>
      <span class="grid_5 omega validation"><span class="formNoError" id="component74">Udfyld navn eller firma for afhentningsadressen.</span></span>
      <span class="grid_5 omega desc" style="display: none;"><p>Navnet på afsenderen.</p></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="grid_3 alpha caption" for="from_address1">Adresse</label>
      <span class="grid_4 body"><input type="text" id="from_address1" name="form[from_address1]" size="20" value=""></span>
      <span class="grid_5 omega validation"><span class="formNoError" id="component75">Udfyld afhentningsadressen.</span></span>
      <span class="grid_5 omega desc" style="display: none;"><p>Adressen på afsenderen.</p></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="grid_3 alpha caption" for="from_address2">Adresse 2</label>
      <span class="grid_4 body"><input type="text" placeholder="etage/lejlighedsnr./e.l." id="from_address2" name="form[from_address2]" size="20" value=""></span>
      <span class="grid_5 omega validation"><span class="formNoError" id="component76">Invalid Input</span></span>
      <span class="grid_5 omega desc" style="display: none;"><p></p></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here's an example you can test: http://jsfiddle.net/KHfcf/ It looks correct. Just be aware that when you hover over any `.body` element, it will toggle *every* `.desc` element.

Comment: That looks good to me (though you might want a semi-colon after each of the two `})`) - is it not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will result in hovering over *any* `.body` element showing *all* `.desc` elements.

If you post your actual markup we can figure out the proper code to show a corresponding `.desc` for a hovered `.body`.

*Update*: So, given the markup in the updated answer I'd probably re-write the handler like so:

```
$('.body').hover( function() {
  $(this).siblings('.desc').toggle();
} );
```

*Update2*: To have the same behavior on click and active is a bit tricky because as soon as you mouseout of the `.body` the `.desc` will hide even if you clicked on it. Doable though... I'd try this:

```
var showFunc = function() { $(this).attr('rel', 'open').siblings('.desc').show(); };
$('.body')
  .click( showFunc )
  .focus( showFunc )
  .hover(
    function() {
      // don't update 'rel' attribute
      $(this).siblings('.desc').show();
    },
    function() {
      // here's the tricky part, if the rel attr is set
      // then dont hide, otherwise, go ahead
      if( $(this).attr('rel') == 'open' ) {
        $(this).siblings('.desc').hide();
      }
    }
  );
```

So this will make it so that just hovering hides/shows as before, but if you click it will 'stick' open. In this case you'd probably want the show handler to also hide other open `.desc`s so that you wont end up tons of open ones all over. So maybe `showFunc` should be:

```
var showFunc = function() {
  $("." + $(this).className).attr('rel', '');
  $(this).attr('rel', 'open').siblings('.desc').show();
};
```

... which will simply clear all other `rel` attributes on previously clicked/focused elements. I'm sure this would still need tweaking, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: You are right... every .desc is now showing. I have updated my question to show the markup. Hope you can help me just getting the corresponding .desc to show. Thanks! :)

Comment: Quick followup... What if I want to .desc to also show on click and active (when tabbing)?

Answer (score 4):

Your script works.

http://jsfiddle.net/y8wPw/

-update-
Your scripts works in different ways according to the JQuery version used. In JQuery 1.3.2 the   `.desc` span will show when you mouseover the `.body` span, but will not disappear when the mouse leaves it. Next time when the mouse enters `.body`. The script reverses it's action and hides the `.desc`. So every time you hover on and off the first span, it'll run the script once.

In JQuery 1.4.2 apparently there's been an update that makes the `.desc` show up on mouseover, but hide immediately on mouseout. I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I believe the change in 1.4 is that passing only 1 function to [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) will cause it to be used for both the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

Comment: Look at that... it does work!? That's pretty weird, but nice to know I got it right!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to just show the `.desc` element of a specific `.body` element you can use the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class='body'>Body content<span class='desc'>description</span></div>
<div class='body'>Body content<span class='desc'>description</span></div>
<div class='body'>Body content<span class='desc'>description</span></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".body").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".desc").toggle();
    })
})
```

**CSS**

```
.desc {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope that helps